# How to push strings into a stack?

Tags: c++, c

I want to push strings like red, blue, and green into a stack

```
//This is my structure containing the stack and top pointer

typedef struct{
    char stk[10];
    int top;
}STACK;

//This is my push funtion

void push(STACK stak, char str[])
{
    stak->top++;
    strcpy(stak->stk[stak->top], str);
    return;
}
```

I want to form a stack like so

```
red
blue
green
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: No. Your stack has **array of 10 characters**, and you're pushing 3 strings to it. What did you get as a result?

Comment: Is this C or C++? Please choose *one* language.

Comment: It crashes. So I need help from you guys. Please correct my program to make it work. Is it possible to push a string into 1 index of a stack?

Comment: you're passing the stack by value, while it should be passed by reference, e.g. void push(STACK& stak, char str[]). Moreover, the body function should be just 'strcpy(stak->stk[++stak->top], str);'

Answer (score 1):

For the basics the answer to your question is definition of stack itself.

> A stack is a basic data structure that can be logically thought as linear structure represented by a real physical stack or pile, a structure where insertion and deletion of items takes place at one end called top of the stack.

What you are doing is creating a stack of chars, and trying to push string to it.
Instead you should create a stack of strings.

```
typedef struct{
string stk[10];
int top;
}STACK;

void push(top,string str)
{
   top++;
   //overflow condition here
   strcpy(STACK.stk[top],str);
}
```

Also a lot of things are different in C and C++, so please decide first which language you gonna stick with. That will help you get better answers.

Comment: didn't know you could have an array of strings. thanks man. newbie here