# Pushing and popping strings into a stack in C

Tags: c, string, stack

I need a way to use strings in a stack. I tried in my code below but I can't seem to make it work. It would crash everytime I try to display the stack. Any type of help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define M 10

typedef struct
{
    char stk[M];
    int top;
}STAK;

void createStack(STAK *stak){
    memset(stak->stk,M,'\0'); 
    stak -> top = -1;
}

bool emptyStack(int top){
    bool empty = false;
    if (top == -1)
       empty = true;
    return empty;
}

bool fullStack(int top){
    bool full = false;
      if (top == (M - 1))
        full = true;
 return full;
}

void push(STAK *stak, char par[]){
    stak -> top++;
    stak -> stk[stak -> top] = par;

 return;
}

char pop(STAK *stak){
    char par;
    par = stak -> stk[stak -> top];
    stak -> top--;

 return par;
}

void display(STAK stak){
    int i;
    for (i = stak.top; i >= 0; i--){
        printf ("%s\n", stak.stk[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    STAK stak;

    bool full, empty;
    createStack(&stak);
    char choice;
    char ln[6];
    do{
        printf("MENU");
        printf("\n\n[A] Park a car");
        printf("\n[B] Pick up a car");
        printf("\n[C] Display all cars");
        printf("\n[D] Exit Program");
        printf("\n\nEnter choice: ");
        choice=tolower(getche());
        system("cls");

        switch (choice){
           case 'a': 
                printf("Input your license number: ");
                gets(ln);
                full = fullStack(stak.top);
                if (full)
                    printf("Garage is full damnit");
                else 
                    push(&stak, ln);

                break;
           case 'b':
                empty = emptyStack(stak.top);
                if (empty)
                    printf("Garage empty.");
                else{
                    //some codes...
                }
                break;
           case 'c':
                empty = emptyStack(stak.top);
                if (empty)
                    printf("Garage   empty.");
                else
                    display(stak);
                break;
           case 'd':
                printf("Program will now end");
                break;
          default: printf("Invalid character. Try again");
                break;
      }

      getch();
      system("cls");

   }while (choice!='d');
}
```

Comment: Each element of your stack can only hold one single character.

Comment: [Dejavu](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36673043/918959)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems:

Check the syntax of `memset` in `createStack` function.

`top` is an element of your structure, not a variable.

You need to use strcpy to copy string on both push and pop functions, don't use assignment operator.

In pop function you are returning a charactor, try to return base address of string array

Edit:
Your code should contain at least an array of pointers to store multiple string.

Comment: Please do these correction and let me now about your output

Comment: If you can understand your problem, please accept my answer